# What does the [‸D] symbol mean in this context?

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh, code-documentation

On the [documentation page for the tcsh complete command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/tcshcomplete.htm), it lists the symbols [‸D] and [‸C] several times. I haven't found anything from Google. Context suggests that they could be single or double tab, but I can find no reference to support this and wanted to make sure it wasn't something more esoteric.

Any ideas what these are meant to represent?

```
    > complete ftp 'p/1/$hostnames/'
    > set hostnames = (rtfm.mit.edu tesla.ee.cornell.edu)
    > ftp [‸D]
    rtfm.mit.edu tesla.ee.cornell.edu
    > ftp [‸C]
    > set hostnames = (rtfm.mit.edu tesla.ee.cornell.edu uunet.uu.net)
    > ftp [‸D]
    rtfm.mit.edu tesla.ee.cornell.edu uunet.uu.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a somewhat unusual way to write `^D`, which is Control+D.

This is the "traditional" mapping to trigger completion, although Tab is more commonly used these days. Back in the day not all keyboards had a dedicated Tab key (the ADM-3A, on which csh was originally developed, didn't) and you would insert tabs with `^I`, there is no real reason to prefer that over `^D` in absence of a dedicated key.